# updating a table conditionally with values from a group by sub query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

the problem is Update the salary of all the employees by 50% who had worked on 5 or more than 5 projects, by 30% (>= 3 projects), by 20 % (>= 1 projects) the number of project is got by performing a group by query on the EMPLOYEE_PROJECT_HISTORY;

i have tried these queries

```
update emp set emp.sal=
case 
when jemp.pcount >=5 then emp.sal+ (emp.sal*50)/100
when jemp.pcount >=3 then emp.sal+ (emp.sal*30)/100
when jemp.pcount >=1 then emp.sal+ (emp.sal*20)/100
else emp.sal+ (emp.sal*20)/100
end 
from employee emp join (select empno as jempno,count(projectno) as pcount from EMPLOYEE_PROJECT_HISTORY by empno) jemp on emp.empno=jemp.jempno ;
```

```
update employee a set a.sal= case (select count(b.projectno) as pcount from EMPLOYEE_PROJECT_HISTORY b group by b.empno ) 
    when b.pcount >5 then
    a.sal = a.sal+ (a.sal*50)/100
    when pcount >3 then
    a.sal = a.sal+ (a.sal*30)/100
    when pcount >1 then
    a.sal = a.sal+ (a.sal*20)/100
    end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to update the join if it contains a GROUP BY clause in Oracle. You can use an inline subquery, like this:

```
UPDATE employee e
   SET sal = sal * (SELECT CASE
                              WHEN COUNT(*) >= 5 THEN
                               1.5
                              WHEN COUNT(*) >= 3 THEN
                               1.3
                              WHEN COUNT(*) >= 1 THEN
                               1.2
                              ELSE
                               1
                           END
                      FROM employee_project_history eph
                     WHERE eph.empno = e.empno);
```

Comment: god ...you are so good ..how can i learn things like this ...i have been banging my head for two days

Comment: @Ramkumar: There are many good sources available on the net to learn. Tom Kytes's website [asktom](http://asktom.oracle.com) is a good place to start. You can find more in this SO question: [Where can I learn more about Oracle databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286260/where-can-i-learn-more-about-oracle-databases). If you like reading books I would suggest [Effective Oracle by Design](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/redirect?tag=asktom03-20&path=tg%2Fdetail%2F-%2F0072230657).